# XMLHttpRequests and ajax within foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have trouble when echoing the decoded array with var_dump. After clicking the button for every row a unique xmlhttprequest and after that a ajax call gets executed thats the theory but in practice the ajax dont work how it should be. If I look at the source code after loading the page all looks well and for every row a unique xmlhttprequest and ajax request becames created

When I run `var_dump($jsonArray)` I get `NULL` What cause this behavior?

**my javascript:**

```
    $("#button1").click( function() {
               <?php foreach ($results as $key => $row): ?>    
                var currentdate = new Date(); 
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        $.ajax({
    url: "insertvolume.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {myData: xmlhttp.responseText},
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(output) {
                      //alert(output);
                  }
});
                    }
                };

               xmlhttp.open("GET","http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20IN%20(%22<?php echo $row["symbol"]; ?>%22)&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env",true);
                 //xmlhttp.open("GET","http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20IN%20(%22LLNW%22,%22AAPL%22)&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env",true);
                xmlhttp.send();

              <?php endforeach; ?> 
         });
```

**Piece of php:**

```
$jsonString = $_POST['myData'];
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonString[0]['query']);
var_dump($jsonArray);
```

**the json array from xmlhttprequest inside the div element:**

```
<div id="output">{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-02-15T16:03:29Z","lang":"de-DE","results":{"quote":{"symbol":"ZN","Ask":"2.05","AverageDailyVolume":"42000"}}}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a json string in `$jsonString` variable but not an array. 
After decoding that string, you'll receive an object of `stdClass`.
Look at the code below:

```
// your json string (the same as in $_POST['mydata'])
$json_str = '{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-02-15T16:03:29Z","lang":"de-DE","results":{"quote":{"symbol":"ZN","Ask":"2.05","AverageDailyVolume":"42000"}}}}';

$obj = json_decode($json_str);
var_dump($obj->query->results);

// the output
object(stdClass)[15]
  public 'quote' => 
    object(stdClass)[16]
      public 'symbol' => string 'ZN' (length=2)
      public 'Ask' => string '2.05' (length=4)
      public 'AverageDailyVolume' => string '42000' (length=5)
```

Comment: Yes youre right, thank you but that doesnt change that I get `NULL` instead of `object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["quote"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) { ["symbol"]=> string(2) "ZN" ["Ask"]=> string(4) "2.05" ["AverageDailyVolume"]=> string(5) "42000" } }` Any other advices? :)

Comment: it's pretty logical. Try `var_dump($jsonString[0])`  and you'll get a single symbol `string '{' (length=1)` as if you were working with 'array of symbols'. Then try `var_dump($jsonString[0]['query'])` and you'll get `Warning: Illegal string offset 'query' `cause you can't treat symbol as  array

Comment: Maybe thats right but my javascript code dont send the results of the json requests to the php file but I didnt know why.

Comment: you mean, `xmlhttp.send()` doesn't work or internal `$.ajax` request ?

Comment: @Bodoppels, add `error` callback to your internal ajax request to handle possible errors: `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }   `

Comment: Thats the curious I get always the success function.

Comment: at http://www.maxiqsoft.com/projeccctss/stocksearch/main.php and http://www.maxiqsoft.com/projeccctss/stocksearch/test.php are demos.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Roman's answer:

```
// your json string (the same as in $_POST['mydata'])
$json_str = '{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2016-02-15T16:03:29Z","lang":"de-DE","results":{"quote":{"symbol":"ZN","Ask":"2.05","AverageDailyVolume":"42000"}}}}';

$results = json_decode($json_str);
$results = $results->query->results;

<?php foreach ($results as $key => $row): 
         echo $row->symbol;
endforeach; ?>
```

You must use $row->symbol, because it is object, not an array.

Comment: I' ve changed now my ajax request that it send it in json format. :)